# UICollectionView UIMenuController get cell

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

I successfully added custom UIMenuItems to the context menu of a UICollectionViewCell.

When using the builtin actions (cut / copy / paste) the `-collectionView:performAction:forItemAtIndexPath:withSender` delegate method gets called.

But it never gets called if invoking custom actions. Is there any easy possibility to get the corresponding UICollectionViewCell from the UIMenuItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example, take a look at this http://paulsolt.com/2012/11/uicollectionview-custom-actions-and-uimenucontroller/

Comment: Thanks. I actually solved the problem quite a long time ago ;) But I think I referred to the same link, though